# UnicodeEncodeError for Accented Characters with json.loads in Python

Tags: python, json, unicode, utf-8, encode

I am scraping a json feed, and then trying to save certain fields to file.

First, I'm getting the json feed using urllib2

```
html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
```

Im then using json.loads

```
data = json.loads(html)
```

Im then trying to grab the 'Name' field for each item

```
for i in range (len(data["response"]["feeds"])):
    Name = str(data["body"]["events"][i]["Name"])
```

Whenever there is an accented character in the "Name" field, python will throw a UnicodeEncodeError

Comment: dont call `str` on it ... that forces ascii which has no accented characters

Comment: what is Name and why is it camelcased

Answer (score 3):

This is a complex issue, which you should take a few moments to understand; unicode vs bytestrings in Python 2.X. I have found Ned Batchelder's Unicode Pain talk at PyCon 2012 to be endlessly helpful in understanding this.

As the pyvideo site is endlessly having troubles keeping videos online, here's a couple links to it:

1. http://pyvideo.org/video/948/
2. http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=sgHbC6udIqc

This is especially important when scraping websites from unknown sources, and unknown encodings!

---

Edit:
To summarize some information from nedbat's talk: You really should know what type of encoding your data comes in as from the target site. `urllib2` will return bytes to you, which may or may not be able to be coerced unicode. In this case, your `Name` field may contain an accented character, which is a type of byte that cannot be converted into the standard ASCII tables (which are A-Z, a-z, 0-9, etc).

The solution is to decode these bytes into `utf-8` (or some other encoding which can handle your accented characters) like so:

```
url = 'http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/unicode-sample.html'  # A page containing raw unicode!
html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read().decode(u'utf-8', u'replace')  # Decode the contents of the page as utf-8 instead of bytes, replacing characters that can't convert into a ? character.
```

Here, you can compare the output of these 2 methods:

```
# Look at the last section of unicode data as bytes. Notice the \xef, signifying bytes, not unicode.
>>> urllib2.urlopen(url).read().splitlines()[-11]
'<dd>\xef\xbc\x81 \xef\xbc\x82 \xef\xbc\x83 \xef\xbc\x84 \xef\xbc\x85 \xef\xbc\x86 ... '

# Now, convert that data into unicode as you open the site.
>>> urllib2.urlopen(url).read().decode(u'utf-8').splitlines()[-11]
u'<dd>\uff01 \uff02 \uff03 \uff04 \uff05 \uff06 \uff07 \uff08 \uff09 \uff0a \uff0b ... '
```

In the first example, you can see that the data comes back as bytes, in the second, it's all unicode data.

This has a few caveats. Not every page can be decoded into `utf-8`, though it would be rare for this to happen.

---

Last piece of advice would be to switch to using the 3rd-party [requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), which will automatically handle unicode for you. An example:

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/unicode-sample.html'
>>> response = requests.get(url)

# You can get bytes out of the response:
>>> type(response.content)  # Returns bytes
<type 'str'>

# Or, you can get unicode out of it:
response.text  # Returns unicode
<type 'unicode'>
```

Using response.text, you can now pass this to `json.loads(response.text)` to successfully get unicode out of the results. Then, remove your `str()` wrapper.

Here's a [link to the requests method reference](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#main-interface) used above.

Comment: -1, link-only answers are not welcome on StackOverflow. Please include a summary of the relevant information from the link, so that your answer can stand on its own.

Comment: @user4815162342. Thanks for the info. Updated my answer to be much much more detailed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Name = data["body"]["events"][i]["Name"].decode('utf8')
```

is most likely what you want

the problem is that you are calling `str(my_variable)`  and `str` will force it to be ascii which does not support accents

Comment: I have tried this, and unfortunately it still throws the same UnicodeEncodeError